# Why isn't position sticky working on my blog article page?

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress, sticky

I've set the parent elements to "overflow: inherit" and ensured the position is correct on all parent elements. However, I cannot seem to get my custom menu ".leftsidebar" to stick past a certain scroll point.

- Made sure parent elements overflows and positioning are not causing the issue
- Tried several other SO discussions to no avail.

  ```
  <nav class="leftsidebar">
     <ul id="stick-menu" class="nav nav-tabs">
        <li class="">
           <a href="#choose-website-platform">Step #1: Choose the Right Platform For Your Website</a>
        </li>
        <li class="">
           <a href="#secure-domain-hosting">Step #2: Secure A Domain Name &amp; Fast Web Hosting</a>
        </li>
        <li>
           <a href="#setup-install-wordpress">Step #4: Setup &amp; Install WordPress</a>
        </li>
        <li>
           <a href="#customize-your-website">Step #4: Customize Your Website</a>
        </li>
     </ul>
  </nav>

  .leftsidebar {
      position: -webkit-sticky !important;
      position: sticky;
      max-width: 30%;
      float: left;
      margin-left: -39.5%;
      top: 100px;
      z-index: 10;
      background-color: transparent;
  }
  #stick-menu {
      z-index: 1;
      width: 100%;
      padding: 5px 0 !important;
  }
  ```

Expected result: The sticky menu should stick until the end of the long article... which is quite lengthy.

Actual result: The sticky menu sticks for a second, but then stops working.

Comment: Sticky seems already working for this code but if so much terrible you can still use fixed or bootstrap

Comment: Here's a link to the STAGING page in question: https://createapro.siteassembly.com

Comment: Which is strange because it's working on other pages on the same site: https://createapro.siteassembly.com/wordpress-homepage-slider/

Comment: I tried on safari browser from phone and mac still seems working for me didn’t stop which brow do you use so i can check it on there

Comment: It's not working for me in Safari, Chrome, or Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

Okey, I found it. In some path your menu in `.entry-content` but main page you have another div which blocks the sticky after some part of the index. Try to take your sticky menu up there like images shown.
[image: This is normal]

[image: This is how shuld be]

Answer (score -1):

`max-width` is the cause

```
.leftsidebar {
    position: -webkit-sticky !important;
    position: sticky;
    max-width: 100%;
    float: left;
    margin-left: -39.5%;
    top: 100px;
    z-index: 10;
    background-color: transparent;
}
#stick-menu {
    z-index: 1;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 5px 0 !important;
}
```

Comment: This is not the cause.